# How do I know my youtube video has buffered sufficiently to play using api

Tags: youtube-api

If I want to make a youtube video seek and then play, using the javascript api, I first need to wait until the video has buffered.  Sometimes the video appears with a circle in the middle going round and round for a while, and I assume that means its buffering.

Is there some event I can listen for that tells me that not only is the player loaded, but the player has buffered enough to seek?

In addition, is there a way of knowing whether the player is in the middle of a seek, so I can wait for the seek to complete, before doing another seek?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There's an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=2915) about adding a "seek" event to the Player API, but I don't have any news beyond what's in that issue tracker entry about if/when it will be implemented.

In general, there's not going to be anything in the Player API added to make it easier to react to different buffering scenarios, because that limits what the Players team is able to do when it comes to changing buffering strategies without breaking things.